# Limit multiple foreach

Tags: php, wordpress

Well, I have a wordpress site containing series and each serie contain episodes, I have this code to get series where isSpecial = 1, then do while to get this serie episodes  with limit 3 for each anime.

```
// Here getting the series
    $args=array(
        'orderby' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => array( 'series', 'movies' ),
        'meta_query' => array(array( 'key' => 'isSpecial', 'compare' => '=','value' => '1'))
    );
    $animes = new WP_Query( $args );
    set_transient( 'animes', $trslidermoved_query_results, 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );


// do while for series
        $i=0;
        while( $animes->have_posts() ) {
            $animes->the_post();
            $i++;
            $animeID[$i] = $post->ID;
            $args = array(
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'fields' => 'all',
                'meta_query' => [['key' => 'episode_number','type' => 'NUMERIC',]]
            );

            $episodes[$i] = wp_get_post_terms(intval( $animeID[$i] ), 'episodes', $args );

// foreach for episodes
            foreach (array_slice($episodes[$i], 0, 3) as $episode) {
} // end foreach

} // end while
```

Now what I want to do is Limit all episodes number to 10 for example

the episodes[1] may get 3 episodes

the episodes[2] may get 3 episodes

the episodes[3] may get 2 episodes

the episodes[4] may get 3 episodes

with my code this will show 11 episode but I want Limit only 10.

So I want to LIMIT the SUM of all foreach not each foreach.

Comment: What is your issue? And question? This is just an explanation of what you're currently doing. Share what you've tried and what happened.

Comment: I want to Limit the sum not each foreach

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is merge all your episode/posts and then slice that array to get the first 10, such as

```
$all_episodes = [];

while () {
  [...]
  array_merge($all_episodes, array_slice($episodes[$i], 0, 3));
}

# Then loop through the first 10 items
foreach (array_slice($all_episodes, 0, 10) as $episode) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: This will break it for each $episode only I want to limit the sum

Comment: It's good idea but array_merge($all_episodes, array_slice($episodes[$i], 0, 3)); not working the array is empty

Comment: Just tested it in a fiddle and it's working fine. Have you tried?